# Is 3rd party Oauth2 Provider in Google DataStudio with custom connectors supported?

Tags: looker-studio

I have an API that a user can query for data after that user authenticates against an OAuth2 provider that I maintain (i.e. not Google).  Is it possible to expose data through this API to Google's Data Studio using a Community Connector?  If yes, is it possible to use the setup outlined here https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#setup against a non-Google OAuth2 provider?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have not found any requisite to expose data through an API. So I expect that it is possible, but take into account the [specific configuration requested](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/oauth2) when implementing it.

The setup outlined there is not official so you will need to test it unless someone has done it already or has enough time for it. The post is really detailed and has work behind, so I would give it a chance!

Comment: The link you provided is actually the official method. For example connector code that use third party OAuth2, see these two: https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/github and https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/meetup

Comment: Great!  Thank you both, working through it, I will report back.